# Sort associative array by values based on another array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I have an array that looks like this

```
array[
   0 => array[
         'id'  => 1,
         'name' => 'Test 1'
         'classId' => 3
       ],
  1 => array[
         'id'  => 1,
         'name' => 'Test 1'
         'classId' => 15
       ],
  2 => array[
         'id'  => 1,
         'name' => 'Test 1'
         'classId' => 17
       ],
]
```

And I have another array that contains `classIds` like:

```
 classIds = [15, 17, 3]
```

And I want to sort my array based on classIds

I can do a a double loop to compare it. I am just wondering is there anyother way to get it done?

Answer (score 0):

Actually one loop i enough:

```
<?php
$order = [15, 17, 3];
$input = [
  [
    'id'  => 1,
    'name' => 'Test 1',
    'classId' => 3,
  ],
  [
    'id'  => 1,
    'name' => 'Test 1',
    'classId' => 15,
  ],
  [
    'id'  => 1,
    'name' => 'Test 1',
    'classId' => 17,
  ],
];
$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($entry) use ($order, &$output) {
  $output[array_search($entry['classId'], $order)] = $entry;
});
ksort($output);
print_r($output);
```

In case you consider `array_search(...)` also a "loop" (though it internally works different), that would be an alternative which produces the same output:

```
<?php
$order = array_flip([15, 17, 3]);
$input = array_values([
  [
    'id'  => 1,
    'name' => 'Test 1',
    'classId' => 3,
  ],
  [
    'id'  => 1,
    'name' => 'Test 1',
    'classId' => 15,
  ],
  [
    'id'  => 1,
    'name' => 'Test 1',
    'classId' => 17,
  ],
]);
$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($entry, $index) use ($order, &$output) {
  $output[$order[$entry['classId']]] = $entry;
});
ksort($output);
print_r($output);
```

The output of both approaches is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Test 1
            [classId] => 15
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Test 1
            [classId] => 17
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Test 1
            [classId] => 3
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array directly and in-place using [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and an anonymous comparison function that retrieves the target indices from `$classIds`.

Given

```
<?php
$arr = array(
   0 => array(
         'id'  => 1,
         'name' => 'Test 1',
         'classId' => 3
       ),
  1 => array(
         'id'  => 1,
         'name' => 'Test 1',
         'classId' => 15
       ),
  2 => array(
         'id'  => 1,
         'name' => 'Test 1',
         'classId' => 17
       ),
);
$classIds = [15, 17, 3];
```

you can sort `$arr` with

```
// Create assoc array mapping classIds to their desired sorted position.
$classIdsOrder = array_combine($classIds, range(0, count($classIds)-1));

// Sort $arr according to the 'classId' order described by $classIdsOrder
usort($arr, function ($left, $right) use ($classIdsOrder) {
    return $classIdsOrder[$left['classId']] <=> $classIdsOrder[$right['classId']];
});

print_r($arr);
```

which outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Test 1
            [classId] => 15
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Test 1
            [classId] => 17
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Test 1
            [classId] => 3
        )

)
```

[Try it online!](https://onlinephp.io/c/984da06d-eea2-4b51-9450-580a4b99c48b)